# Did the Canadian Tuxedo emerge out of the Wool Shortage of 1973?

Tags: economy, canada, fashion

I understand that the [Hudson Bay Company](http://globalnews.ca/news/275667/canadian-tuxedo-makes-an-entrance-on-international-fashion-stage/) is responsible for the proliferation of the "Canadian Tuxedo".  The Canadian Tuxedo is described as a denim jacket with jeans.  The denim jacket must have patches on it to fully qualify. However, I can't place a date on when this was done.

The wool shortage I refer to is mentioned in this [Chicago Tribune article](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1973/03/04/page/348/article/wool-shortage-affects-carpets/).  I understand this must have caused a change in consumer fashion and I have to imagine that it would have meant that making clothes out of cotton would be a suitable alternative.  However, I don't know if the wool shortage was that bad in that it would have made such longer lasting fashion trends.

Anyone have any firm dates on when the Canadian Tuxedo emerged and whether these two events are linked?

Comment: Damn interesting question.

Comment: Denim jackets predated your wool shortage. 'The first denim jacket was created circa 1880 by denim legend and Levi's founder Levi Strauss'.

Comment: Jeans and other clothing made of cotton (and other fibers) were common long before 1973.  Certainly where I grew up, wool was (and still is) rather a rarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the denim jacket was first made in the late, 1800's, the phrase 'Canadian Tuxedo' actually has its source from the 1950s, when an [incident occurred](http://www.levistrauss.com/unzipped-blog/2014/05/throwback-thursday-the-denim-tuxedo-is-officially-making-a-comeback/) at a Canadian Hotel:

> In 1951, Crosby and a friend were denied entrance into a Canadian
>   hotel because they were dressed entirely in denim. When Levi’s
>   designers caught wind of the incident, they created a custom jean
>   tuxedo for Crosby, ensuring that he would always be able to wear his
>   beloved Levi’s in any fine establishment.
>   [image]

So the source of 'Canadian Tuxedo" definitely predates the above mentioned 1973 wool shortage.

See also

[urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Canadian%20Tuxedo)

[Levi's Vintage Clothing Brings Back The Original "Canadian Tudo"](https://www.gq.com/story/levis-vintage-clothing-bing-crosby-denim-tuxedo)

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm still trying to figure out if the wool shortage caused a shift in working men's attire to make the denim jacket more ubiquitous than otherwise.  Wool jackets, such as the red-black, seem to have declined as well as the wool capes worn by women.